# Prob. 7, Sec. 3.3, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS, 4th ed: Is this sequence convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Here is Prob. 7, Sec. 3.3, in the book *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $x_1 \colon= a > 0$ and $x_{n+1} \colon= x_n + 1/x_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Determine whether $\left( x_n \right)$ converges or diverges.

My Attempt:

> We note that $x_1 = a > 0$. Suppose that $x_k > 0$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $$ x_{k+1} = x_k + \frac{1}{x_k} > 0. $$
>   Therefore $$ x_n > 0 \ \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}. $$
>
> We note that for any natural number $n$, as $x_n > 0$, so we have 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left( \sqrt{x_n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n} } \right)^2 +  \left( \sqrt{x_n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \right)^2 \right] \geq \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left( \sqrt{x_n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n} } \right)^2 -  \left( \sqrt{x_n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \right)^2 \right] = 2.   $$
>   Thus we can conclude that $$ x_n \geq 2 \ \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that } n \geq 2. \tag{0} $$
>
> Now suppose $\left( x_n \right)$ is convergent, with limit $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then as $x_n \geq 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 2$, so we must have $x \geq 2$. Then we must have 
>   $$ x = x + \frac{1}{x},  $$
>   which implies that $$ \frac{1}{x} = 0, $$
>   which is impossible.
>
> Hence our sequence cannot converge in $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as $x_n > 0$, so we have 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{x_n} > x_n. $$
>   Thus our sequence is strictly increasing.
>
> As our sequence is monotonically increasing and not convergent, so it is not bounded from above. Therefore we can conclude that 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = +\infty. $$

Is what I have done so far correct and accurate? If not, then where are the problems?

Comment: No problem with what you wrote. The part showing that $x_n\ge2$ does not seem necessary to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Why has my post been down-voted, I wonder? What've I done wrong?

Answer (score 4):

@Saaqib your method is nice. Just wanted to add something.

---

You can prove that the sequence is monotonically increasing by looking at the ratio $ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} $.

$$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} =1 + \frac{1}{x_{n}^{2}} > 1 $$
and we know that $x_{1} > 0$, so we must have the sequence $x_{n}$ strictly increasing.

---

Or another way, use induction : $x_{1} > 0$, then assume $x_{k} > 0, \:\: k \in \mathbb{N}$, then 
$$ x_{k+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{x_{k}} > 0 $$
so by induction, we conclude that $x_{n} > 0$. Then notice that 
$$ x_{n+1}-x_{n} = \frac{1}{x_{n}} >0 $$
so the sequence is strictly increasing.